# How do I insert timeseries data into Solr?

Tags: solr, time-series

I have existing Solr collection named chronix.

ANd I also have configured chronix, but when I issue query on chronix JAVA FX then it is throwing error like this -

```
2018-06-29 09:30:16.611 INFO  (qtp761960786-20) [   x:chronix] o.a.s.c.S.Request [chronix]  webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=*:*&fl=%2Bdata&start=0&rows=200&wt=javabin&version=2} status=500 QTime=1
2018-06-29 09:30:16.611 ERROR (qtp761960786-20) [   x:chronix] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `+` before the value in your `fl` parameter. The `fl` parameter should contain the list of fields you want to retrieve, and having a `+` here is not a valid field name.

To get the field `data` back, `&fl=data` is what you want, not `&fl=+data` (`%2B` is the url encoded version of `+`)

Comment: Ok Thanks for your reply. Yes you are right I was using '+' in fl parameter.

Sir I have below data to insert into Solr :-
    {
 "name" : "aditya",
"type" : "metric",
"start" : 1530246082100,
"end" : 1530246082200,
"data" : binary_data
}

So in this data how should I insert data for this binary field?

Comment: For binary data, [use a binary field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/field-types-included-with-solr.html). Ask a new question and provide the proper details there if you have an issue not related to your original question.